# where can I find *.erl files after installation kazoo 2600hz

Tags: erl, kazoo

where can I find or develop *.erl files on my server after installation kazoo 2600hz  I can't see any .erl file !

I installed kazoo correctly and it work 
but I cant find files to develop
is this about permission?

Answer (score 0):

The Kazoo RPM installs its files under `/opt/kazoo`. You will find the `.erl` files in sub directories under this folder. You can update the source, run make in the appropriate directory (i.e. the first folder with a `Makefile` up from the `.erl` file you edited) and then restart the service to run your changes.